# SSIS - Slowly Changing Dimension - Latest data only

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids

I have a table with nearly 10 million records.  We are in dire need to perform a Type 2 data warehouse table and a slowly changing dimension to populate that table.  That is the easy part.

The hard part is, I want to understand how I can ONLY have the SSIS package look at the items where the items modified date is 72 hours or less than the current date; this would cause the package to run quickly the second time around.  I can have the Slowly Changing Dimension run off of a view that has this filter in it. BUT I do not want it to expire the records that were not in the last bunch of data.

Is there any tutorials hopefully including screen shots of what I can do to make this all happen smoothly?  I have searched and searched and have found nothing, but I am pretty sure that this is something very easy to do.

Comment: Sounds like you may not want to use the SCD component for a fast solution.  You can manually implement the SCD logic with Lookups, Conditional Splits, Derived Columns, etc.  Robert Cain talks about this in his Pluralsight course on DW Design patterns - he calls it a "Set based" pattern.  If you want to keep the SCD component, you would want a Conditional Split - one split with logic to expire, the other without.  Take this with a grain of internet-salt, as I've only explored SSIS for about a year.

Answer (score 0):

The SCD wizard will generate a "Historical Attributes Inserts Output" dataflow, which will pass through a Derived Column transform, then an OLE DB Command transform.  That last component is where the expired records will be updated.

You can edit the SQL code in that transform, or delete this component and reconnect the dataflow.